# Manually editing a dumped pickle file in python

Tags: python, pickle

I have two classes`ClassA` and `ClassB` with the same content and structure but just with different names. I saved an object of `ClassA` using `pickle.dump` to a binary file. However, I want to now load it in a different program which only has access to `ClassB`. Loading this file using `pickle.load` fails now as it can't find the `ClassA` description and thus throws some error like `No module named ClassA exists`.

To solve this, I manually investigated the saved binary file, and found the required class name `ClassA` coded in ASCII in the file. I guessed that it was looking for this exact class name, which resulted in the above error. Upon changing this name from `ClassA` to `ClassB` inside this binary file, the code seemed to be correctly loading the object, but now as `ClassB`. Which is what i wanted.

However, since i manually edited this file, I was wondering if there would be any adverse effects down the line for doing this. Or is it, if it works it ain't stupid scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a more explicit coded example? It is not clear why you should have two identical classes with different names.

Comment: I don't have access to my work computer right now. But I'll try explaining the situation a bit more. ClassA is a data structure class which resides in a huge library with many other class definitions, So accessing this involves the full name ParentX.SubParentY.ClassA. However it has no dependencies except numpy. I need this object data dump for another project where ParentX is unavailable. So I copied the class definition of ClassA, but the pickle obj dump has a hard coded name of ParentX.SubParentY.ClassA. So it was easier to change this name, rather than import the entire ParentX library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the pickle formats use offsets into the file or any kind of compression or encryption, so changing the name is fine even if it changes the length.  You have to know that the text “ClassA” doesn’t appear for some other reason, of course, and that your editor won’t mangle the file—say, by trying to do character decoding/encoding.

That said, in this situation I’d probably create a dummy package to give `ClassA` the correct name rather than edit the pickle.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The dummy package idea is quite nice, I'll do this instead of my hacky way.